# how I can enable when I click in. notch in iOS go top of screen

Tags: ios, flutter

Generally speaking, it is only available on ios.
When I click on the notch above it takes me to the top of the page

It works on a pre-application for me, but in the current application it does not work, I don't know how to do it or something like that.

[Explanation of the location of the notch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4RAv.jpg)

Comment: Yes, correct
But it did not answer my question. In another application, I used the same library. View List and it worked fine, here no.

Comment: Note it only gets triggered on `PrimaryScrollController` classes and nothing else. Check the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619421-scrollstotop

Answer (score 0):

may this help:

```
Scaffold(
  body: 
    Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) => 
      CustomScrollView(controller: PrimaryScrollController.of(context))
```

OR

may be this will help, [scrolls_to_top](https://pub.dev/packages/scrolls_to_top):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScrollsToTop(
      onScrollsToTop: _onScrollsToTop,
      scaffold: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Scroll to top')),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onScrollsToTop(ScrollsToTopEvent event) async {
    //TODO: Your code
  }
```

reference: [reference](https://mixable.blog/flutter-enable-scroll-to-top-for-nested-scaffolds-e-g-in-indexedstack/)

Comment: Thank you, but it is a feature that already exists, so I don't think it is necessary to write a code?

Comment: natively, yes, but in Flutter, I don't think it exists...

Comment: Me too for those who knew but
  Yes, it is there, it works well with another application for me, but I do not know what is the difference between them.

Comment: may be conflict between Scaffold and scrollview widget? i've updated some code

Comment: It doesn't work when you click on it, I also printed a message to whomever appears

It seems that no action is happening on the state bar, so I don't know why